# Expect element to not include text

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, nightwatch.js

I can write `.assert.containsText('#output', 'find me')`
to have NightWatch to find text in a div.

But how do I tell NightWatch to expect not to find text in an element?

**Updated with working example**

```
  module.exports = {
    'Fetch data using the default JSON format': function (browser) {
      browser
      .url('http://localhost:5000')
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
        .clearValue('input[type=text]')
        .setValue('input[type=text]', 'http://localhost:5000/advertisers')
        .click('#fetchButton')
        .pause(1000)
        .assert.containsText('#output', 'MockAdvertiser')
        .expect.element('#output').text.to.not.contain('xml');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Expect API](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-api) instead of the Assert API like this:

```
browser.expect.element('#output').text.to.not.equal('Do not find me');
```